# Get all Json elements when convert String to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have a json code in this link: [here](http://www.fredericmme.com/mobileapp_php/news.php)

I'm trying to parse it by that code:

```
  JSONObject jsonObj;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            System.out.println("jsonObj: "+jsonObj);

            jArray = new JSONArray();
            jArray.put(jsonObj);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it gives just the first element. How to get all elements of the JSON?

Comment: The link is of an json array. Simply parse your json string in a JSONArray object. This will do it

Comment: I tried to do this but it gives me `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: Your `JSON response` is invalid. It gives a `Unexpected token error`.

Comment: Actually the problem is your method put method of Json Array is uses when you want to appends your current json Array are you trying to append your Json Array

Comment: I recommand you to follow this link for Json Parsinghttp://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

That is a invalid JSON, you need to add '{"": your_JSON_here }' andit will work

Your code will be like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{\"\":"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            System.out.println("jsonObj: "+jsonObj);

            jArray = new JSONArray();
            jArray.put(jsonObj);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I know that's invalid JSON. Please add a sample code for ` {"": your_JSON_here }`

Comment: It gives me `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`